# jdbc with oracle DB - out of memory

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I've written a simple code that reads a table from oracle DB.

I try to run in on a very big table and I see that it consumes a huge amount of memory.

I thought that using fetchsize will cause it to optimize memory usage (that what happens when using it on SQLSERVER), but it didn't. tried it with various values  - from 10 to 100000.

Can't see how I manage to perform a simple task - export a very big oracle table to a csv file.

I use ojdbc6.jar as a driver.

also I use

connection.setAutoCommit(false);

Any idea?

Comment: Show us your Java code. I bet you are storing each row somewhere. It is certainly possible to run an export from a really big table without running out of memory (I'm doing that all the time)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like creating the statement with ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY solved this problem.